# How to default to different drop down options using different PHP variables

Tags: php, html, forms, if-statement, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make it a little easier for our sales staff to use our order panel. I'd like to have a dropdown ("sales department") default to the correct department if a certain value is detected in my `$dept` variable.

Thing is, I feel like there HAS to be a better way of approaching this problem than doing this:

```
<?php if($dept == 'web') { ?>

    <select class="select" name="dept">
        <option value=“web” selected="selected">Website Orders</option>
        <option value=“phone”>Phone Orders</option>
        <option value=“retail”>Retail Orders</option>
    </select>

<?php } elseif($dept == 'phone') { ?>

    <select class="select" name="dept">
        <option value=“web”>Website Orders</option>
        <option value=“phone” selected="selected">Phone Orders</option>
        <option value=“retail”>Retail Orders</option>
    </select>

<?php } else { ?>

    <select class="select" name="dept">
        <option value=“web”>Website Orders</option>
        <option value=“phone”>Phone Orders</option>
        <option value=“retail” selected="selected">Retail Orders</option>
    </select>

<?php } ?>
```

Is there a way I could change the default setting of this dropdown without repeating the HTML three times? I'm a pretty novice PHP programmer, so more elegant solutions still elude me most of the time. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this, just adapt it to fit in your web template and pull the right data into the setup vars in the first two lines...

```
$depts = array('web' => 'Website Orders', 'phone' => 'Phone Orders', 'retail' => 'Retail     Orders');
$dept = 'phone';
echo '<select class="select" name="dept">';
foreach ($depts as $deptKey => $deptName) {
    $line = '<option value="' . $deptKey . '"';
    $line .= ($dept == $deptKey) ? ' selected="selected">' : '>';
    $line .= $deptName . '</option>';
    echo $line . "\n"; 
}
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an efficient way of doing it. I mean you could probably be more "pretty" but if it works why change it? the only other way I could think of is, if you're using a framework, you could pass in a variable into a template to decide what dropdowns you're going to use.

Comment: "Pretty" I guess. :) I'm really hoping to not have to needlessly repeat code.